# Is there a way to do dynamically-weighted addition of loss functions in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In my code, I have two custom loss functions. One is the negative log likelihood (NLL), the other is the KL divergence (KLD).

Each of these is calculated separately and added to a `tf.keras.Model` using `model.add_loss(NLL)` and `model.add_loss(KLD)`.

For the first `x` epochs, I want only the NLL to be encorporated but after that I want the KLD to gradually increase its influence (annealing). My desired structure is:

```
weight_KL {epoch 00 -> 09} == 0.0
weight_KL {epoch 10 -> 19} += 0.1
weight_KL {epoch 20 -> ..} == 1.0
```

The way that I see this is that there are two loss functions added together with a weight which changes over each epoch:

```
total_loss = NLL + weight_KL * KLD
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in TensorFlow 2?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a simple, reproducible example?

Comment: Are you open to using `GradientTape` instead of `model.fit()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `callbacks` argument in `model.fit()`. Add your loss adjustment inside the inbuilt function `on_epoch_begin` or `on_epoch_end` as per requirement.

Define your Callback function something like below :

```
# Define the Required Callback Function
class LossCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    if (epoch < 3):
      model.add_loss(NLL + KLD)
    else:
      model.add_loss(NLL + KLD +0.1)
```

And your `model.fit()` should look like below -

```
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=4, callbacks=[LossCallback()])
```

You have several more option in `callbacks` like `on_batch_begin`, `on_batch_end` etc, you can find them [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @evanr70 - Can you please upvote and accept the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.